# Why can't we use top-down methods in forecasting grouped time series?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, multilevel-analysis

As I asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210688/what-is-proper-way-of-forecasting-grouped-time-series-specified-via-hts-package) I was trying to forecast grouped time series with two grouping variables and I find some limitation of hierarchical forecasting methods. In particular, using *hts* package from R, **we can't use top-down methods.**

I consider grouped time series which can be viewed as:

```
     Total
   |       | 
   A       B
 |   |    |   |
AX  AY   BX  BY

     Total
   |       | 
   X       Y
 |   |   |   |
 AX  BX  AY  BY
```

(It's described in more details in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/forecasting-hierarchical-time-series-r-package) and for example in this [paper](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/hgts6.pdf))

According to the notation specified in [this paper](http://robjhyndman.com/papers/Hierarchical6.pdf) we can write such grouped time series as $\mathbf{Y_t} = \mathbf{S} \mathbf{Y_{K,t}}$, where $\mathbf{S}$ is a summing matrix and $\mathbf{Y_{K,t}}$ is a vector of bottom level series (which according to assumption in hts package have to be equal). In this case it looks like:

$$   \begin{bmatrix}
  Y_t \\
  Y_{A,t} \\
  Y_{B,t} \\
  Y_{X,t} \\
  Y_{Y,t} \\
  Y_{AX,t} \\
  Y_{AY,t} \\
  Y_{BX,t} \\
  Y_{BY,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  Y_{AX,t} \\
  Y_{AY,t} \\
  Y_{BX,t} \\
  Y_{BY,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Revised forecast (what I am looking for) can be written as $\mathbf{\tilde{Y}_n(h) = SP\hat{Y}_n(h)}$ and in case of top-down method matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is defined as 
$\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{p} | \mathbf{0}_{m_K \times (m-1)} 
\end{bmatrix}$, where $ \mathbf{p} = [p_1, p_2, ..., p_{m_K}]^T$  is a vector of proportions. Not going into more details, in this example $m_K = 4$ and $m=9$, so $\mathbf{P} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{p_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\mathbf{p_2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{p_3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{p_4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

and revised forecasts can be written as:

$$   \begin{bmatrix}
  \tilde{Y_t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{A,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{B,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{X,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{Y,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{AX,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{AY,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{BX,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{BY,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 1  \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\ 
 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 p_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
p_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
p_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
p_4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
  \hat{Y_t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{A,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{B,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{X,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{Y,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{AX,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{AY,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{BX,t} \\
  \hat{Y}_{BY,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and after calculations:

$$   \begin{bmatrix}
  \tilde{Y_t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{A,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{B,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{X,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{Y,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{AX,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{AY,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{BX,t} \\
  \tilde{Y}_{BY,t} \\
 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  p_1\hat{Y_t} + p_2\hat{Y_t} + p_3\hat{Y_t} + p_4\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_1\hat{Y_t} + p_2\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_3\hat{Y_t} + p_4\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_1\hat{Y_t} + p_3\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_2\hat{Y_t} + p_4\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_1\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_2\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_3\hat{Y_t} \\
  p_4\hat{Y_t} \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Which seems OK for me. I was hoping that somebody could point out **why this method can't be used in forecasting grouped time series** and point out when my calculations are wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top-down methods implemented in the `hts` package were designed for hierarchical time series. If you want to define your own top-down method for some non-hierarchical time series, go right ahead. It's not wrong, it just hasn't been implemented in the `hts` package because there are much better solutions to the problem.

The best approach currently available is to use weighted least squares as explained in http://robjhyndman.com/working-papers/hgts/. This is the default in the `hts` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!  It definitely clarify usage of top-down forecasting method in case of grouped time series. (*hts* package is a great contribution in practical applications)

Answer (score 2):

Further to [Rob's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163658/1352), let's look at your specific example:

```
     Total
   |       | 
   A       B
 |   |    |   |
AX  AY   BX  BY

     Total
   |       | 
   X       Y
 |   |   |   |
 AX  BX  AY  BY
```

You have not one, but *two* hierarchies. For instance, the top one may group sales at product-location level first by location A and B and then add these up to get the Total, and the second one may group first by product X and Y and add these up.

To do top-down forecasting, you forecast the Total and then break this down by proportions. You can use historical proportions, in which case, yes, you can do this.

*The problem arises if you want to use **forecasted** proportions* to break down the Total forecasts. Why? Because if you forecast your component series A, B, X, Y separately, these forecasts will usually not be sum consistent. That is, if you first break the Total down to A & B and then break A down to AX & AY, you may get a different result for AX than if you first broke down to X & Y and then broke X down to AX & BX.

Thus, you will need to do some kind of reconciliation. And then, as [Rob writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/163658/1352), you might as well use the "real" optimal reconciliation approach.

(Note that this problem does not arise if you use *historical* proportions to break forecasts down, because these are automatically consistent. However, historical proportions do not allow you to forecast out changing dynamics in your hierarchy, like changing market shares.)